# creating a read-only user in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a user that can only read from a database. This is the user creation screen on phpMyAdmin. For the first set (`Data`), I figured I only need `SELECT`. But I'm not sure about the second and third sets (`Structure` and `Administration`). Some options like `Event` `Trigger` `Execute` are a bit confusing. Do I need those for a read-only user? What exactly do I need to enable/disable?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the user should only be able to read the database, they should not be granted **any** of the permissions listed under "Structure" or "Administration".

Answer (score 5):

First section is only about managing with table's data and you only need `SELECT` privilege to have a read-only user.

Answer (score 4):

Disable everything in 'structure' and 'administration'. There's is no point in giving a person read-only rights on a table/db while leaving them the ability to completely destroy that same table/db.