# Enable remote access to phpmyadmin in read only mode

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to give the remote access to the phpmyadmin in the intranet in the read only Mode.
Is it possible to do so?

I tried in httpd-xampp.conf by changing the require local to require all granted.
But this changes allow users to made changes in my data.

I made the changes in

````
```<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
```AllowOverride AuthConfig
```Require local
```ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
```</Directory>

To the below

```Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
```<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
```AllowOverride AuthConfig
```Require all granted
```ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
```</Directory>

Need to allow all user to see the data only and not be able to change from remote access. The data can be only change from localhost.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a user with read only access, then user can only see the data,

command line code

```
grant select on database_name.* to 'read-only_user_name'@'%' identified by 'password';
```

or you can [follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503614/creating-a-read-only-user-in-phpmyadmin)